# No START clause VS. n = node(*)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've read in Neo4J 2.0 docs that `START` clause is optional and

> Cypher will try and infer start points from your query

I have experimentally found that

```
START user = node(*) 
MATCH (user:User)-[r:KNOWS]-(user2:User) 
RETURN user.username AS username, collect(user2.username) AS username2
```

gives the same results as

```
MATCH (user:User)-[r:KNOWS]-(user2:User) 
RETURN user.username AS username, collect(user2.username) AS username2
```

for small data sets.

My question is: is it semantically the same? Will they always return same result set (I'm not talking about the order)? Even for large data sets? Does skipping `START` guarantee traversing all nodes? If they are semantically equal why would one ever use `node(*)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your queries are not semantically the same, but they will always return the same result. The reason they will return the same result is that in your first query, having stated the 'universal node pattern' `node(*)` you immediately limit it with a further pattern in your `MATCH` clause. In your second query you state this more narrow pattern from the start, but since the two `MATCH` clauses are equivalent and the most narrow pattern declared in each query (and since the `RETURN` clauses are the same) the two queries return the same results.

The `START` clause used to be the way to state the initial pattern for a query and it was tied up with indexing. Using `node(*)` or `relationship(*)` was rarely recommended or useful, but the clause was used for index retrievals, as in `START user=node:userIndex(name="Maciej Ziarko")`. With 2.0 labels and label indexing was introduced and this is now the preferred way to bind nodes in a query.

Skipping `START` will not guarantee traversing all nodes (or perhaps more accurately: binding all nodes), but neither do you need a `START` clause to do so. Using `MATCH user` (without limiting what is bound to `user` with labels or relationships) you can still bind every node in your database. It is still rarely recommended or useful.